# Does Java internally use Hashing technique to manage all objects

Tags: java, hash

new to the hashing concept, I have read that HashMap, HashTable etc use hashing, and we need to specify a key while storing a value with it

But, since every object has a hashCode() method, doest java internally use hashCode for a object via a particular field while managing it (other than the lists)

Comment: What sort of thing are you thinking of?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear; are you asking whether Java uses the `hashCode` method for its own internal purposes?

Answer (score 2):

This is answered by the [javadoc of Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (**This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer**, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

(emphasis mine)

So no, there is no additional field to store the hashCode (unless some class decides to override it and implement it by using a dedicated field).

And the hashCode is not used by the JVM, but by hash-based collections (Hashtable, HashMap, HashSet, ...)

Comment: You can't use the internal address of an object because that changes on every modern generational or compacting GC because these operations move objects around in memory.

In addition the default hash code is part of the mark word of the object header http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/raw-file/1ee8caae33af/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp so it's sort of a field on every object.

Comment: I don't think the javadoc meant the physical memory address, but only the JVM-internal "logical" memory address. I see it as something like the path of a file, which uniquely identifies a file on the file system, and could be considered as its "internal address" in the file system, although it isn't the physical address on the disk.

Comment: There is no JVM-interal "logical" memory address. OOPs are straight native pointers http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/docs/whitepaper/Java_HotSpot_WP_Final_4_30_01.html#pgfId=1082238

Answer (score 2):

No, the hashCode() method is used to define a key used to associate it with an instance of an object.

It is used to identify a particular instance of an object, and does not imply that a hashing technique is used to manage Java objects.

You can override the hashCode() method to define your own way of assigning keys to identify an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking "does Java use `hashCode()` in order to do behind-the-scenes management of objects?", I would imagine the answer is "no".  Consider what would happen if you wrote a really bad override of `hashCode()`; would you expect the JVM internals to be hampered by this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public native int hashCode();
```

`hashCode` is native implementation. But no field is associated with it.

```
This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required
by the JavaTM programming language.
```

In the OpenJDK/Oracle JVM the usual method of computing the initial hash code is based on the memory address at the time of the first request. Objects move about in memory, so using the address each time would not be a good choice. The hash code isn't the actual address - that would typically be a multiple of eight which isn't great for using straight in a hash table particularly with a power of two size. Note identity hash codes are not unique.

As per documentation

```
jvmtiError GetObjectHashCode(jvmtiEnv* env, jobject object, jint* hash_code_ptr)
```

and

```
For the object indicated by object, return via hash_code_ptr a hash code. 
This hash code could be used to maintain a hash table of object references, 
however, on some implementations this can cause significant performance 
impacts--in most cases tags will be a more efficient means of associating 
information with objects. This function guarantees the same hash code value 
for a particular object throughout its life.
```

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong file, you're probably looking at `jvmtiEnv.cpp`, this JVMTI which is for tools like debuggers and profiles. This will just read the hash code from the mark word http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/raw-file/1ee8caae33af/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp. You want to look at `synchronizer.cpp` http://blogs.tedneward.com/2008/07/16/ObjecthashCode+Implementation.aspx